# Trying to install VvirtualBox on Kali Linux 2016.1 (install virtualbox-dkms not working)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux

I followed the regular procedure of installing VirtualBox on Kali. However, when I go to run VirtualBox, I get these responses from the terminal, and this pop up error message:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I did as the pop up and terminal told me and installed the virtualbox-dkms packages.

Then I go to load the code module as it says by using the command `modprobe vboxdrv`, and I get this error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64.
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is the problem with yours but I had a similar problem trying to install VirtualBox in Kali and a lot of others did too!

I think the problem is in the headers you need to download the right virtualbox for your headers try this it worked for me!
check linux-header version:

```
uname -r 
apt-get autoremove virtualbox
apt-get update && upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then reboot

```
sudo su 
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) //it will probably not install
```

Anything since the kernel should be upgraded when running `dist-upgrade`.

Then run:

```
apt-get install virtualbox
```